# Ardunio Errors with ATmega644A Fastled (MCUDude Mightycore)

Tags: arduino, atmega, ws2812b

Good Morning,

I am trying to compile a ardunio project with ATmega664A using the MCUDude MightyCore plug in while using the Fastled library.

I have used this before with ATtiny167 with [Spence Konde ATtinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore) which has worked with no issues.

I am currently having the following error message but am not too sure on where to go next.
[image: Error messages]
If I could have some recommendations on what the errors are and potential fixes that would be great.

Comment: The errors read there. What they mean should read in some sort of manual for the library/module you are using. Perhaps folks at Arduino Stackexchange can help, as this is purely "how to use Arduino libraries" type of programming question.

Comment: @Justme thank you for that. I did not know there was such a thing.

Comment: The board support package, it would seem, does not define the relevant macros for SPI MOSI, MISO, and SCK

Comment: cross posted here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89576/ardunio-errors-with-atmega644a-fastled-mcudude-mightycore

Comment: @vicatcu can you expand on this plesae